# How to create a proximity placement group after VM and disks have been created?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-managed-disk

I have created 2 VMs and couple of disks.

Some of these disks are shared disks (part of wsfc cluster), and some disks are non-shared.

I want to add all the VMs and disks into a proximity placement group.

How to create a proximity placement group after VM and disks have been created?

Answer (score 2):

> I want to add all the VMs and disks into a proximity placement group.

> You cannot add **Azure Disks** to an **Azure proximity placement group** as it is designed to group Azure compute resources such as **Virtual Machines** and **Virtual Machine Scale Sets**.

An `Proximity Placement Group` is primarily used to logically group `Azure compute resources` that are physically located in close proximity within the data center. This grouping aims to reduce latency and improve application performance. Here is the [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/co-location#proximity-placement-groups) about `Proximity Placement Groups`.

For adding multiple `VMs` to `Proximity Placement Groups` at once, you can use `PowerShell`.

Here is a `PowerShell` script to add existing `VMs` to `Proximity Placement Groups`

```
    $resourceGroup = "venkattests-resources"
    $location = "West Europe"
    $pgname = "sampleProximitygroup"
    $zone = "1"
    $vmsize1 = "Standard_E64s_v4"
    $vmsize2 = "Standard_M416ms_v2"
    $ppgn = New-AzProximityPlacementGroup -Location $location -Name $pgname -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -ProximityPlacementGroupType Standard -Zone $zone -IntentVMSizeList $vmsize1, $vmsize2
    $vms = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup
    
    foreach ($vm in $vms) {
    
        # Stop the VM before making changes
        Stop-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $vm.Name -Force
    
        # Update the VM with the Proximity Placement Group
         $vm.ProximityPlacementGroup = $ppgn.Id
    
        Write-Host "Adding VM: $($vm.Name) with Proximity Placement Group: $($ppgn.Name)"
    
        Update-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -VM $vm
    
         Write-Host "Updated VM: $($vm.Name) with Proximity Placement Group: $($ppgn.Name)"
    
        # Start the VM again
    
        Start-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $vm.Name
    
    }
```

**Result:**

[image]

All `VMs` in the resource group have been added to the `Proximity Placement Group`

[image]

Reference: [Add existing VM to placement group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/proximity-placement-groups-portal#add-existing-vm-to-placement-group)

Comment: If I create 2 VMs with 4 managed disks (shared) without proximity group then will the disks reside in same data center as VM1 or VM2?

Comment: Without using a **proximity placement group**, the placement of disks and VMs is subject to Azure's default allocation strategy. In Azure, disks and VMs are not guaranteed to be placed in the same datacentre unless you specifically configure them to be close together using **placement groups**.

Comment: Ok - if I create 1 VM and 4 disks. Now is there any guarantee that the VM and disks are in same data center? If not, then do you agree that proximity placement groups are not a compute only concept but also apply to data disks?

Comment: When you create a single VM and multiple data disks in Azure without using proximity placement groups, there is no guarantee that the VM and disks will be in the same data canter but Proximity placement group allows you to ensure that both your VMs and the associated data disks are in VMs placed in close physical proximity within the same data center,providing the proximity needed for optimized performance and low-latency connections but If you create disks separately and try to add them to a PPG, it won't work.

Comment: My confusion is because your answer states `You cannot add Azure Disks to an Azure proximity placement group as it is designed to group Azure compute resources such as Virtual Machines and Virtual Machine Scale Sets.`

Comment: Yes, as per [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/co-location#proximity-placement-groups), proximity placement groups are designed for Virtual Machines and Virtual Machine Scale Sets. However, if the disks are associated with VMs and VMs, the concept can apply to those as well. But if you create Azure Disks separately and try to add them to a proximity placement group, it won't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255641/discussion-between-venkat-v-and-variable).